# Why should I not use equals with inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, equals

When I read a Java book, author has said that, when designing a class, it's  typically unsafe to use `equals()` with inheritance. For example:

```
public final class Date {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
         // some code here
    }
}
```

In the class above, we should put `final`, so other class cannot inherit from this. And my question is, why it is unsafe when allow another class inherit from this?

Comment: What's the name of the book?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because it's hard (impossible?) to make it right, especially the [*symmetric* property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Say you have class `Vehicle` and class `Car extends Vehicle`. `Vehicle.equals()` yields `true` if the argument is also a `Vehicle` and has the same weight. If you want to implement `Car.equals()` it should yield `true` only if the argument is also a car, and except weight, it should also compare make, engine, etc.

Now imagine the following code:

```
Vehicle tank = new Vehicle();
Vehicle bus = new Car();
tank.equals(bus);  //can be true
bus.equals(tank);  //false
```

The first comparison might yield `true` if by coincidence tank and bus have the same weight. But since tank is not a car, comparing it to a car will always yield `false`.

You have few work-arounds:

- strict: two objects are equal *if and only if* they have exactly the same type (and all properties are equal). This is bad, e.g. when you subclass barely to add some behaviour or decorate the original class. Some frameworks are subclassing your classes as well without you noticing (Hibernate, Spring AOP with CGLIB proxies...)
- loose: two objects are equal if their types are "compatible" and they have same contents (semantically). E.g. two sets are equal if they contain the same elements, it doesn't matter that one is `HashSet` and the other is `TreeSet` (thanks *@veer* for pointing that out).

  This can be misleading. Take two `LinkedHashSet`s (where insertion order matters as part of the contract). However since `equals()` only takes raw `Set` contract into account, the comparison yields `true` even for obviously different objects:

  ```
  Set<Integer> s1 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
  Set<Integer> s2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1));
  System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
  ```

Comment: Not *impossible*; see e.g. [`Set.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz as your link give me, if we use `if (this.getClass() != tank.getClass()) {return false;}` or `if (this.getClass() != tank.getClass()) {return false;}`, the problem will be solved. Can you tell me more about this case.

Comment: @hqt: have a look at *strict* section of my answer. If such restriction was added e.g. in `java.util.Date` class, you would never be able to compare it with `java.sql.Date` - BTW which is probably not a good idea to begin with.

Answer (score 12):

Martin Odersky (the guy behind generics in Java and the original codebase for the current `javac`) has a nice chapter in his book *Programming in Scala* addressing this problem. He suggests that adding a `canEqual` method can fix the equality/inheritance problem. You can read the discussion in the first edition of his book, which is available online:

[Chapter 28 of Programming in Scala, First Edition:
Object Equality](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html)

The book is of course referring to Scala, but the same ideas apply to classic Java. The sample source code shouldn't be too difficult for someone coming from a Java background to understand.

***Edit:***

It looks like Odersky published an article on the same concept in Java back in 2009, and it's available on the same website:

[How to Write an Equality Method in Java](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)

I really don't think trying to summarize the article in this answer would do it justice. It covers the topic of object equality in depth, from common mistakes made in equality implementations to a full discussion of Java `equals` as an equivalence relation. You should really just read it.